# Asp.net core razor page or MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Am going to develop one client web application which uses data from existing seperateapi project data. Initially I thinking angular application but limited  javascript  knowledge I thought blazor server side will suit me..but I found that some of the limitations now am re thinking my client application in MVC or razor page. 
My question is

1.is it possible to do use same layout for razor page and razor views?

2 .if not possible can develop with razor page alone? Pls let me know limitations for medium scale projects

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer :

1.is it possible to do use same layout for razor page and razor views?

Yes you can use same layout for both with minor changes.

2 .if not possible can develop with razor page alone? Pls let me know limitations for medium scale projects.

You can develop medium scale project with both however there are some limitation related to filters in razor pages but work around is available for those limitation.

Let me know if you have further query.

Comment: Thanks.is routing is same for both?

Comment: routing is not very difficult..in case of ajax there are some differences..go through below sites https://www.learnrazorpages.com/